# calling a function containg enum in java

Tags: java, enums

I have defined a class

```
class Prop{
    public static enum property{
    NAME,
    CITY,
    ADDRESS;
    }
    private String NAME;
    private String CITY;
    private String ADDRESS;
    public String getValue(property pro){
    switch(pro){
    case NAME:
    return NAME;
    case CITY:
    return CITY;}
    return null;}
    }


class CallPro{
   private String name;
   name=Prop.getValue("");
 }
```

I am not exactly getting how to call getValue from class CallPro.

Basically what parameters should be passed to get the desired value.

I am a beginner in java

Comment: Do you know [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) Site from Oracle? What are you trying to achieve btw? Can't you use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name() ?

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable. Moreover use general coding conventions - like class names start with a capital letter etc.

Comment: @BluesSolo I have edited the code hope now it is fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run this program you need a `public static void main(String[])` method first. That's your entry point into any Java program. Since, you want to assign the values inside `callPro`, add the `main()` method there.

Next, you want to call `getProperty()` which is an instance method belonging to class `prop`, so you'll need to create an instance of it first using the *new constructor()* syntax.

```
class callPro {

    private static String name;
    private static String city;
    private static String address;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create prop instance
        prop property = new prop();

        // call prop's method getValue()
        name = property.getValue(prop.property.CITY);
        city = property.getValue(prop.property.NAME);
        address = property.getValue(prop.property.ADDRESS);
        // New York, John, Central Park
        System.out.println(name + ", " + city + ", " + address);
    }
}
```

Notice, how I had to make `callPro`'s members `static` to be able to access them inside the `main()` method because that's `static` too. Also, note how I referenced the *Enums*: *className.enumType.enumValue*.

To be able to see the values print from the `main()` method, you'll also need  to provide values for your `prop` class members as

```
private String NAME = "John";
private String CITY = "New York";
private String ADDRESS = "Central Park";

public String getValue(property pro) {
    switch (pro) {
    case NAME:
        return NAME;
    case CITY:
        return CITY;
    case ADDRESS:
        return ADDRESS;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Yes, you can loop through an *enum*'s values and retrieve your properties in a loop as

```
prop property = new prop();
for (prop.property prop : prop.property.values()) {
    System.out.println(property.getValue(prop));
}
```

*enumType.values()* returns an *enumType[]* of all *enumValues* which can be used with a `for-each` loop as shown above.

Comment: can't it be done by using a loop or by some other method instead of  calling all the variables individually, as the number of variables are more than 20 :P